# How to create a search functionality involving two tables without same attributes?

Tags: php, laravel

I copied http://justlaravel.com/search-functionality-laravel/ to make my search functionality.

**web.php**

```
<?php
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

Route::get ( '/', function () {
    return view ( 'welcome' );
} );

Route::any ( '/search', function () {
    $q = Input::get ( 'q' );
    $user = User::where ( 'name', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%' )->orWhere ( 'email', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%' )->get ();
    if (count ( $user ) > 0)
        return view ( 'welcome' )->withDetails ( $user )->withQuery ( $q );
    else
        return view ( 'welcome' )->withMessage ( 'No Details found. Try to search again !' );
} );
```

and this is the view, in which the results are displayed

**View**

```
<div class="container">
@if(isset($details))
    <p> The Search results for your query <b> {{ $query }} </b> are :</p>
<h2>Sample User details</h2>
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($details as $user)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
            <td>{{$user->email}}</td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
@endif
</div>
```

So, if for example I have a User Table which is presented here, with a name and email column. at the same database I have a Dogs Table which has breed column and color column.

if I want the search box to search on both tables and display results from both tables(if they both have the same value) what should I add to this code ? Thank you very much.

Comment: You should use controller instead of writing all codes in route file. If two tables have some relationship then you can join them and get search to find desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Route::any ( '/search', function () {
$q = Input::get ( 'q' );
$results = array() ;
$user = User::where ( 'name', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%' )->orWhere ( 'email', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%' )->get ();
$dog = Dog::where ( 'breed', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%' )->orWhere ( 'color', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%' )->get ();
$results['dog'] = $dog ;
$results['user'] = $user ;
if (count ( $results['dog'] ) > 0 || count ( $results['user'] ) > 0 )
    return view ( 'welcome' )->withDetails ( $results )->withQuery ( $q );
else
    return view ( 'welcome' )->withMessage ( 'No Details found. Try to search again !' );
} );
```

and in view foreach on $results['dogs'] and $results['user'] in the correct places

and also you should do this all in controller instead of routes